# Sorting of hash by specific params - undefined method `sort_method' for Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a hash `collection` which I want to sort by `declared_params[:sort]`. So I wrote something like that

`collection.sort_method(declared_params[:sort])`

but I've got an error

> undefined method `sort_method for #Hash:0x00007ffaafcab140>

The hash `collection` which I want to sort looks like:

```
{
  data: [{
    id: "1",
    type: :credit_campaign,
    attributes: {
      name: "Credit Campaign #1",
      interest_rate: 12,
      start_date: "Fri, 04 Oct 2019",
      end_date: "Mon, 04 Nov 2019",
      total_campaign_codes_amount: 15,
      used_campaign_codes_amount: 0
    }
  }]
}
```

declared_params: `{ "page" => 1, "per_page" => 10, "sort" => { "id" => "desc" } }`

Comment: Where did you get this `sort_method` from? There's no such method in Ruby as well as in Rails, as far as I know.

Comment: @MarekLipka I think it is from some gem but I don't know tbh. Is there any other method to sort that hash?

Comment: @mr_muscle The error is that no such method exists. And indeed, no such method *does* exist in ruby. So if you're unable to say where you expect this method to be defined, then the answer to your question is: *The method does not exist*.

Comment: @TomLord Ok so instead of `sort_method` what should I do to get this hash sorted by e.g. `name` or `total_campaign_codes_amount` or id ? this is used in an admin panel where admin have to have ability to sort things by these parameters.

Comment: Need to define `sort_method` to sort data.

Comment: @mr_muscle What do you expect the result to be? What other arguments do you want to pass into this method (e.g. Do you also want to sort by `'attributes.interest_name' => 'desc'`)? And also, `id` is a `String` -- so unless you also want to perform some implicit conversion conversion to `Integer`, you'll get weird results in the ordering for IDs `9, 10, 11` for example - have you considered this?

Comment: As it currently stands, you haven't stated what you want the code to do, and it fails for the simple reason that the called method does not exist. Unless you clarify the requirements significantly, I must unfortunately vote to close the question as it's very unclear what you are asking.